# photoshop script distort smart object and finding coordinates

Tags: javascript, photoshop, photoshop-script

I'm trying to make a few scripts in javascript for photoshop cc 2019 windows 10 64 bit and there are a few things I can't find out how to do:

1. Finding out the 4 corners coordinates in a Transform / Distort of a smart object and being able to manipulate them.
2. Being able to store click position coordinates, possibly to use with the previous thing.
3. - a) No idea if it's possible but finding the location of those 4 corners in a black/white mask.

     [image: image showing four corners]
   - b) An alternative would be finding the coordinate of a layer's center.

Basically, I want is to use a script to:

- Deform a smart object so that it fits a black and white image or mask that has 4 corners.
- Or in the case of 3b) it would be deforming a smart object so that it moves each corner of it to the center of some layers with specific names.
- And another script that waits for the user to click 4 places, stores the coordinates and then the smart object deforms into them.